# Not able to invoke the API Services when something is between Controller and Service in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have **Product.js** file where

```
var productOPS = {

    GetProduct: function () {            

        var promiseGet = getProducts();       
    }};
```

Now I want to invoke **ProductService.js**

```
app.service('crudService', function ($http) {

    ///product GET

    this.getProducts = function () {
        return $http.get("/api/ProductsAPI");
    }

    ///end product    

});
```

And **ProductController.js** is

```
app.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService) {

    GetProducts();

    //Function to load all Employee records
    function GetProducts()
    {

        productOPS.GetProduct();
    } } });
```

How can I invoke the Service from GetProduct of Products.js and pass the value back to ProductController

**Error: getProducts() is not defined.**

Comment: Why are you using seperate product.js file?

Comment: because once the data is received, i need to do some more operation on the data. Which looks nasty in controller.js... that's why i want to have a seperate JS file

Comment: Where you are linking Product.js and your controller file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service should return object

```
app.service('crudService', function ($http) {
    return {
      getProducts: function () {
          return $http.get("/api/ProductsAPI");
        }
});
```

and then in controller you can sue it like this:

```
app.controller('crudController', function ($scope, crudService) {
  crudService.getProducts().then( function(response){
    $scope.products = response.data
  });
});
```

`$http` returns promise that's why I used then but you can do success or whatever you want

Comment: Cannot I get service result in a seperate JS file . I need to process that

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's separate file as long as it's scope of the same app